# UIcollectionView weird cell recycling behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with flow layout, about 140 cells each with a simple UITextView. When a cell is recycled, I pop the textView onto a cache and reuse it later on a new cell. All works well until I reach the bottom and scroll back up.  At that point I can see that the CollectionView vends cell number 85, but then before cell 85 is displayed it recycles it again for cell 87 so I now lose the content of the cell I had just prepared.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FormCell", for: indexPath) as! FormCollectionViewCell
   let textView = Cache.vendTextView()
   textView.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
   cell.addSubview(textView)
   cell.textView = textView

   return cell

}
```

And on the UIcollectionViewCelC

```
override func prepareForReuse() {

   super.prepareForRuse()
   self.textView.removeFromSuperView()
   Cache.returnView(self.textView)

}
```

I would have thought that after cellForItemAtIndexPath() was called, it would then be removed from the reusable pool of cells but it seems it is immediately being recycled again for a neighbouring cell. maybe a bug or I am possibly misunderstanding the normal behaviour of UICollectionView?

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of you manually reusing text view like that? Why can't it just be a part of the cell?

Comment: the textView is just an example, in reality the views are more complex and so the recycling cache allows smoother performance by not having to create so many objects at run time and simply modifies one from the Cache

Comment: Your caching mechanism is redundant, because you're basically doing exactly the same thing that collection view is doing, only (probably) less efficiently.

Comment: the CollectionView recycles cells, it would be fine if every cell I had was going to be exactly the same or was known before run time, but in my case it is not, so I am attempting to cache the contentView of the cells so they can be modified and vended again when required.

Comment: You're not caching anything that can be reliably restored later, because you store the text view, but don't even keep the information about which cell / index path it comes from. And that still makes what you're doing pointless - why can't you just have text view as subview of cell, store the text when the cell goes out of screen, and restore just the text when it comes back?

Comment: As I just told you, not every cell has a textView this is just an example, the reality is a lot more complex, lets imagine you had 15000 cells, all potentially different content views that you do not know until run time, you cannot design cells for that, so you must create your contentViews at run time. You have a couple of options then, you can create them all before hand and simply index them in an array (massive memory usage) or you can create a caching system that takes one as needed and modifies it.. obviously the data required to populate the views in the model must be indexed.

Comment: UICollectionView cell does not reused in the same indexPath as it was previously. so when you scroll back to top the cells are re-rendered with different indexpaths

Comment: That's not how collection views work

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, what you're trying to do is just keep track of cell content - save it when cell disappears and restore it when it comes back again. What you're doing can't work well for couple of reasons:

1. `vendTextView` and `returnView` don't take `indexPath` as parameter - your cache is storing something and fetching something, but you have no way of knowing you're storing/fetching it for a correct cell
2. There's no point in caching the whole text view - why not just cache the text?

Try something like that:

Have your `FormCollectionViewCell` just have the text view as subview, and modify your code like so:

```
class YourViewController : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate 
{
    var texts = [IndexPath : String]()

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
    {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FormCell", for: indexPath)
        if let formCell = cell as? FormCollectionViewCell {
            cell.textView.text = texts[indexPath]

            return cell
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
        didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, 
               forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if let formCell = cell as? FormCollectionViewCell {
        {
            texts[indexPath] = formCell.textView.text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that the indexpath  here "texts[indexPath]" will be same as reusable cell indexPath ?